# Class constraints JAVA to C# implemetation

Tags: c#, java, .net, c#-4.0

Java implementation:

I have this abstract class:

```
public abstract class Base<T> {}
```

and the derived:

```
public class MyClass<W extends Base> {}  //Compiles and works just fine
```

Note : in JAVA i don't need to add the generic type  to Base when declaring Base as constraint.

.Net implementation

```
public class MyClass<W> where W : Base  //Doesn't compile
public class MyClass<W> where W : Base<T> //Doesn't compile - (what is T ?)
```

I need to be able to declare a generic class as constraint without specifying the generic Type (Just like in JAVA)
Can i do that in .Net ???

Comment: isn't the java version better if `MyClass<W extends Base<?>>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `T` in the list of generic type parameters:

```
public class MyClass<W, T> where W : Base<T>
```

*Usage:*

```
var myObject = new MyClass<ClassExtendingBase, string>();
```

with

```
public abstract class Base<T> { }

public class ClassExtendingBase : Base<string> { }
```

Comment: how to use it, `new MyClass<Derived<String>, String>`?